# Create custom GitHub emojis

Tags: github, emoji

GitHub seems to have a rich set of emojis it supports.

https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/7360908

I am looking for a green triangle face down.

There is a red triangle face down, however, I am looking for precisely this, but in green.

It's code is

```
:small_red_triangle_down:
```

I. naively, tried doing `:small_green_triangle_down:` but that doesn't seem to be defined. Is there a way I can get a green colored triangle face down in GitHub ?

Answer (score 1):

Considering [`rxaviers/7360908`](https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/7360908) seems to be a *complete* list of supported emojis at GitHub, if you don't see yours, chances are it is not supported through those `:xxx:` shortcuts.

Even [emojipedia.org](https://emojipedia.org/search/?q=triangle) doesn't list any other color for that triangle.